# How to have a fully self contained app that can be stood up independent of azure?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, vue.js

I was told today by management that the plan is to have a fully self-contained app that can be stood up independent of Azure?

Can anyone explain this process to me?

The technologies we're using are vue.js/node.js/express/MySQL database that's being hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick guide:

You have to install an image of an OS (Debian or ubuntu recommended) and then you have to install the packages nodejs and mysql-server

In debian/ubuntu you can install them like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Once node is installed you have to use npm to install express and vue (npm is a package manager for node that comes with node installation)

```
npm install -g express
npm install -g vue
```

Then you have to make sure that the mysql service will be always running, in debian/ubuntu it usually works if you run

```
sudo systemctl enable mysqld
```

This command tells the system to run this service after every reboot